# File fails to upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here is my routes file

```
Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');

Route::get('welcome', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/item', 'ItemController@store');

//Route
Route::post('/item', ['as' => 'item.store', 'uses' => 'ItemController@store']);
```

Here is my store controller

```
public function store(Requests\CreateItem $request)
{
    Item::create($request->all());
    $file = $request->file('filename');
    if (Input::hasFile('filename')) {
        echo 'Uploaded';
        $file = Input::file('filename');
        $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}
```

My upload form does not return any errors, but this snippet of code is not moving my uploads to the folder specified. What am I doing wrong? I am using Laravel 5.2.

edit: Here is my form

```
   {!! Form::open(['url' =>'route' => 'item.store', 'files' => true]) !!}
    {!! Form::label('name', "Name") !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

   {!! Form::label('filename', "File Name") !!}
    {!! Form::file('filename', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('description', 'Description') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Add Item', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
```

EDIT 2: Now I'm getting the following error upon accessing the form

> FatalErrorException in 41b177cdb949fd0263185e364012b35dff81db06.php line 7: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'

EDIT 2 Now I get this error everytime I try to access the add item form:

> FatalErrorException in 41b177cdb949fd0263185e364012b35dff81db06.php line 7: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'

Comment: is the echo printed?

Answer (score 16):

Another reason for this is PHP max upload size.
Increase value and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Does the `<form>` have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on it?  It needs this to send the files properly.  It's practically an error whenever a `<form>` has `<input type="file">` elements in it, but doesn't have that attribute.

This is a pretty common mistake, gets people all the time.

Comment: I'm using Laravel, and there's a special command for this. It's part of the framework's blade.php system

Comment: Your Form::open has url and route, bad syntax.  Maybe it got cached without files, then?  If in doubt, you should still verify the output of the Form helper.  It's just a helper.

Comment: Okay, I'll try verifying the form helper's data.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a coma and a key

```
{!! Form::open(['url' =>'route' **, 'key'** => 'item.store', 'files' => true]) !!}
```

and you should use url or route, but not both.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'item.store', 'files' => true]) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything seems fine, then you need to check your file. Test your upload with a different file with a lower size.

For me, it was solved when I resized the image.